# assign to Excel series for chart according to value in row

Tags: excel, excel-tables

If I have a table or range in excel I want to show in a table (with 2 series) like this :

| X Value | Y value | Series |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FEE | first |
| 2 | FI | first |
| 1 | FO | second |
| 2 | FUM | second |

Rather than having a specific static subrange for each series defined on the chart, I want the row included in to the series depending on the value of the series column. E.g. if I changed the third lines 'series' value from second to first it would change the displayed ranges from:

1: FEE-FI

2: FO-FUM

to

1: FEE-FI-FO

2: FUM

...Without me having to update the data selections, and so my table will be updated.

Is this possible simply? I've seen an alt solution where new columns are defined or not depending on value of series value but bit complex, wonder if there is some easier way I am missing?

Comment: Does your version have TEXTJOIN?

Comment: Mac 2019 so yes!

Comment: Then something like: `=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,IF(C:C="first",B:B,""))` Which on a PC requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array enter.